# Removing separate IF statements

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am wondering what type of alternatives are best to use in this situation.

```
if (method1(parameters)
  method2(parameters);
if (method1(differentParameters)
  method2(differentParameters;
//and so on.
```

The code is for an othello game implementation, the first method checks if there are any opponent pieces that can be fliped, the inner method flips the pieces. We check all 8 directions to and flip pieces accordingly.

The code works, but I am searching for alternatives to refactor it.

Comment: Could you share the real code? Its a bit difficult to find proper alternatives on such a vague example. Most proper solutions are likely more specific to the actual situation at hand.

Comment: *the one that returns true will be excuted. if/else can't be implemented because all of the given if need to be checked* - this part is a bit inconsistent. If you know that only one of them can be true at a time, `else` can be used so after finding the `true` one, the rest can be skipped. However if you have 8 `if`s where any amount of them may run at a time, then collecting them at a single place as you do now is probably the most what can be done.

Comment: I agree for seeing your actual code. It gives us a better idea what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

If seems to me your method1 is a `Check` and your method2 might be called `Flip`.
It seems to me you issue can be easily encapsulated like this:

```
CheckAndFlip(params) {
   if (Check(params)) 
      Flip(Params)
}
```

And then call

```
CheckAndFlip(params);
CheckAndFlip(otherParams);
...
```

which looks a lot better for me.